# How to convert a timestamp (without timezone) from one timezone to another in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

How do I convert a timestamp without timezone (e.g. `2016-05-26 13:00:00.000000`) from say `PST` to `UTC` in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

Simply do: `$input::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE $src AT TIME ZONE $dest` e.g.:

```
SELECT event_timestamp::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM events;
```